# How to implement ten-fold cross validation in LibSVM

Tags: validation, libsvm

I am already able to run the examples in the LibSVM package. Now i need to carry out the ten-fold cross validation(MATLAB) on a data set. How do i go about doing it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use the '-v 10' option in libsvm.. it will do the cross validation for you...

Comment: Sorry can you explain what it is cross validation ? Thanks