# why we need cross validation in multiSVM method for image classification?

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, classification, svm, cross-validation

I am new to image classification, currently working on SVM(support Vector Machine) method for classifying four groups of images by multisvm function, my algorithm  every time  the training and testing data are randomly selected and the performance is varies at every time. Some one suggested to do cross validation i did not understand why we need cross validation  and what is the main purpose of this? . My actual data set consist training matrix size `28×40000` and testing matrix size `17×40000`. how to do cross validation by this data set help me. thanks in advance .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cross validation is used to select your model. The out-of-sample error can be estimated from your validation error. As a result, you would like to select the model with the least validation error. Here the model refers to the features you want to use, and of more importance, the `gamma` and `C` in your SVM. After cross validation, you will use the selected `gamma` and `C` with the least average validation error to train the whole training data.

You may also need to estimate the performance of your features and parameters to avoid both high-bias and high-variance. Whether your model suffers underfitting or overfitting can be observed from both in-sample-error and validation error.

Ideally [10-fold](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14024740/10-fold-cross-validation-in-one-against-all-svm-using-libsvm) is often used for cross validation.

Comment: It seems misleading to call SVM "relatively immune" to over-fitting. Depending upon the data and training method you can certainly overfit. Linear SVM is less prone to overfitting than non-linear, but in either case it's a risk.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with multiSVM but you may want to check out libSVM, it is a popular, free SVM library with support for a number of different programming languages.

[Here](http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/libsvmtools/#cross_validation_with_different_criteria_auc_f_score_etc) they describe cross validation briefly. It is a way to avoid over-fitting the model by breaking up the training data into sub groups. In this way you can find a model (defined by a set of parameters) which fits both sub groups optimally.

For example, in the following  picture they plot the validation accuracy contours for parameterized gamma and C values which are used to define the model. From this contour plot you can tell that the heuristically optimal values (from those tested) are those that give an accuracy closer to 84 instead of 81.

Refer to [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14024740/10-fold-cross-validation-in-one-against-all-svm-using-libsvm?rq=1) for more detailed information on cross-validation.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You always need to cross-validate your experiments in order to guarantee a correct scientific approach. For instance, if you don't cross-validate, the results you read (such as accuracy) might be highly biased by your test set. In an extreme case, your training step might have been very weak (in terms of fitting data) and your test step might have been very good. This applies to ALL machine learning and optimization experiments, not only SVMs.
To avoid such problems just divide your initial dataset in two (for instance), then train in the first set and test in the second, and repeat the process invesely, training in the second and testing in the first. This will guarantee that any biases to the data are visible to you. As someone suggested, you can perform this with even further division: 10-fold cross-validation, means dividing your data set in 10 parts, then training in 9 and testing in 1, then repeating the process until you have tested in all parts.